# Mysql output without truncating

Tags: mysql

So if I open up a Mysql CLI and run a select statement that includes many columns and row content that is long, mysql will render this depending on my window resolution. If my screen is small and a row doesn't fit, it will cut in half and display the second half of the row on a second line. I am looking for a way to output the rows as a continuous line (so they can be read easily) and then use a command to tab to the right and see the second half of the content. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the `--vertical` commandline option which will print a column:value pair on each line, rather then wrapping lines.

With the `--pager` option you should be able to use a different pager, such as less, more or a custom one.

The MySQL [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html) has a number of examples to use a custom pager, including the following example:

```
mysql> pager less -n -i -S
mysql> select * from mysql.user;
```

And then scroll from left to right...

> In the preceding example, note the -S option. You may find it very
>   useful for browsing wide query results. Sometimes a very wide result
>   set is difficult to read on the screen. The -S option to less can make
>   the result set much more readable because you can scroll it
>   horizontally using the left-arrow and right-arrow keys. You can also
>   use -S interactively within less to switch the horizontal-browse mode
>   on and off. For more information, read the less manual page.